# SPARQL how to use concatenated strings for a subject of a subquery?

Tags: concatenation, sparql, wikidata

I created a SPARQL query like below. I get `?year` and `?month` from SERVICE query in Wikidata, and would like to use them as a part of a subject of a subquery (i.e. `?uri ?p ?o` part). I managed to concatenate ?year and ?month and generate a URI, but somehow the the query does not return a result.

I tested both the subquery part (e.g. only using `<https://example.com/date/10-1> ?p ?o`) and the SERVICE query individually. They both return results properly (13 and 5 results respectively, so the size is not an issue). My guess is it is concatenated variable is a string not URI, which cannot be a subject. But I am not sure. As I am not sure what is wrong, I tried similar queries, but they get time-out, due to the subquery I think. Can you spot the problem and let me know how to fix it? Many thanks in advance!

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?event ?eventLabel ?d1 ?d2 ?d3 ?date ?year ?month ?uri ?p ?o
WHERE {

 SERVICE <https://query.wikidata.org/sparql> {
    select DISTINCT ?event ?eventLabel ?d1 ?d2 ?d3 ?date ?year ?month
    where{
      ?event wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q13418847  .
      ?event wdt:P276 wd:Q1741  .
      OPTIONAL {?event wdt:P580 ?d1}
      OPTIONAL {?event wdt:P585 ?d2}
      OPTIONAL {?event wdt:P582 ?d3}
      BIND(IF(!BOUND(?d1),(IF(!BOUND(?d2),?d3,?d2)),?d1) as ?date)
      BIND(year(?date) AS ?year)
      BIND(month(?date) AS ?month)
      SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE], en". }
   }
   ORDER BY ?date
   LIMIT 100
 }
 BIND(CONCAT("<https://example.com/date/", str(?year), "-", str(?month), ">") AS ?uri) .
  
 {
  SELECT ?uri ?p ?o 
    WHERE {?uri ?p ?o .}
  LIMIT 10
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`IRI` function](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-iri) to make the string (without the `<`/`>`) into a URI:

```
BIND(IRI(CONCAT("https://example.com/date/", str(?year), "-", str(?month))) AS ?uri) .
```

Comment: you should also mention that the URI is **not** propagated into the subquery, that's a misunderstanding for many people. In fact, it's just a join on the result of the subquery, which in the current case can lead to an empty result as a `LIMIT 10` is used. It might work by chance ... the correct way would be to put the `SERVICE` and the `BIND()` clause into the subquery